# http request or webclient with windows phone

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone

i am newbie for windows phone app.Can anyone tell me how can i perform HTTP request with post method step by step .I search a lot on Google not found any solution .Please help me.I got error : {Invalid Request}. My database is in MySQL.I am using visual studio 2012 ultimate.

Comment: Find my answer for the same question [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18058974/request-response-windows-phone/18072726#18072726


Check this one.

Comment: I refer link given by you but it will give me error that is invalid request .i want to login authentication in my app.for that username and password  is user input.now can you explain me in that context.?it will more helpful to me.

Comment: If you're new to Windows Phone then [I'd recommend WebClient as it's easier to use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528675/post-method-in-webclient)

Comment: Neil Turner i refer your link.But when i click on button there is nothing  done .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find samples for just about everything Windows Phone either on:

- The WP dev site - http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/
- The Nokia developer samples or WP - https://developer.nokia.com/Develop/Windows_Phone/Code_examples/ (might have to log in first)

Specifically for your request you should check the following examples which all detail how to do HTTP requests / results on WP

- http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Making-an-await-WebClient-dd9a53d8
- https://projects.developer.nokia.com/wprssreader
- http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/display-from-an-RSS-feed-2bcd7369